# Google Firebase MLKit Vision API tweaking block bounds

Tags: ocr, google-vision, firebase-mlkit

I am experimenting with Google's new Firebase MLKit for iOS. I am playing with cloud text recognition in images, and am wondering how I can tweak the bounds of the text blocks.

This is the sample I am using: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/recognize-text

I can find documentation on doing this for Google's Cloud Vision, but not specifically for the MLKit implementation of Cloud Vision.

Text from images is being automatically placed into blocks. Some returned blocks should be combined, and others should be seperated. How can I go about tweaking the rules in which these blocks are generated. Refer to the sample provided.

Comment: Could you link to the API you're referencing in Cloud Vision?

Comment: Hi, I think I have a similar problem but I'm developing an android app. I wanna scan a shopping receipt to get items and prices but the ML Kit makes various blocks and so prices and items are not in same line in the result. Now I try to get the CornerPoints of the blocks or lines and try to save it in a multidimensional array to sort it by position to get the correct lines.